# Assigning different randomly generated values to each rows (python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dummy-data

I am trying to make a dummy data where I would like to assign random sentences under the question column.

I am using `from essential_generators import DocumentGenerator` to generate the random sentences.

```
for i, row in dummy.iterrows():
    dummy['Question'] = gen.sentence()
```

I thought if I iterate each row and apply gen.sentence(), which randomly generates a sentence each time, i would get different sentences for my data of 1000 rows. However, it is result in giving me the same sentence for all 1000 rows.

What can I do to yield my desired result?

Comment: Could you show how `gen` is initialized?

Comment: gen = DocumentGenerator()

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, row in dummy.iterrows():
    row['Question'] = gen.sentence()
```

This is probably what you're looking for. I can't advise more as I'm not getting enough information from your question.

Answer (score 1):

`dummy['Question'] = [gen.sentence() for _ in dummy.index]`

EDIT: on the right-hand side we use list comprehension to create a list with `len(dummy.index)` number of elements. We iterate over `dummy.index`. `_` by convention is just throw-away variable name - i.e. we don't care about it. we just need to call `gen.sentence` certain number of times.

Comment: I get 'int' object is not iterable error message when I run this :(

Comment: sorry, I fixed it

Comment: It worked! Thank you. If it is not much of trouble, can I ask you what you did there? especially for _ in range() part?

Comment: It's just iterating the dummy array I guess. ```_``` means that you don't care what the variable is.

Comment: @KaiShengTung, I didn't see the OP comment. I edited my answer. Note that we don't iterate over `dummy`. We just create a list of sentences and assign them to `dummy[Question]`

Answer (score 0):

```
dummy['Question'] = dummy.apply(lambda row: gen.sentence(), axis=1)
```